# Making an IOS app where i need to update content regularly (few times a day)

Tags: ios

im planning to make an app where i can send tips for a particular subject to the app daily (a few times a day), as easily as possible, which the user will be able to see as soon as i have sent the data. Ideally with some kind of notification too.

The best way i can think of doing it is to have the tips coming from a web page which i can update, like a blog maybe as i have no experience in web design yet (although not ruling it out if thats the only way then i will learn). However as i will be charging a subscription fee on the app, i dont want anybody to be able to see the supporting website, that would just be there for me to enter the data.

I hope this is clear, im not looking for specific code or anything just a practical way to do it! If theres a better way then please let me know. Also i want to have the option to make it an android app as well as IOS, but if not IOS is priority. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For iOS, using Push Notifications when you got tips updated on your server.  So when users received and responded to your Push Notifications messages, your app got opened and handled appropriately.  You can use Push Notifications service from [Parse](https://parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications) if you don't have server to do it.

I would imagine similar concept existed in Android.

Comment: Ok thanks for the push notification tips, but  the actual tip will need to be displayed in the app and remain there even when the next tip comes. So for example the notification will say 'you have a new tip' then the user will open the app and it will be there for them to read?

Comment: Using PN just so your users know there are new tips.  Once users responded to the PN,your app will need to download from your server(new tips)/store (using CoreData, etc.), displaying, etc.......